# Spring tool suite error 13 : Windows 8.1 and JAVA 8

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Cannot start sts - it gives me below error - I am using Windows 8.1; JAVA Version 1.8.0_20 - not sure whats going wrong

[image: error message screenshot]

```
    -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
    -product
    org.springsource.sts.ide
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
    256M

    -vm 
    T:/softwares/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/javaw.exe 
    -vmargs

    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
    -Xms40m
    -Xmx768m

    -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
```

I have tried changing JAVA_HOME path even added -vm args but nothing seems to work...Since I am running JAVA 1.8 I have added the required version as 1.8 not sure if that's the issue? Any help much appreciated. It gives me ERROR Code 13 constantly

Answer (score 4):

I can't see the image that you mentioned, but I guess this is a mismatch between the STS version that you downloaded and the JDK that you are using with regards to 32bit vs. 64bit. It looks like you downloaded the 64bit version of STS. Are you sure that the JDK 1.8.0_20 that you have installed is a 64bit JDK as well? Error code 13 is often related to this kind of mismatch.